# Popup window shows after kernel closed when using J/Link

Tags: java

A popup window always show after `kernelLink.close();` And this **only happen** after expression evaluated as graph. Such as `evaluateToTypeset`
[image]

I got the suggestion from JLinkUserGuide in 'Graphics and Typeset Output' chapter bellowed:

> It is very important to note that you execute `CloseFrontEnd[]` before
>   closing the link to the kernel. This is essential to prevent the front
>   end from quitting in circumstances where it should not~specifically,
>   if an already-running copy was used and the user has open documents.

But this does not work.
This's my code of init `KernelLink`

```
System.setProperty("com.wolfram.jlink.libdir", "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64");
KernelLink kernelLink = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink("-linkmode launch -linkname /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/Executables/MathKernel -mathlink");
        kernelLink.connect();
        kernelLink.discardAnswer();
```

Close `KernelLink`

```
kernelLink.evaluateToOutputForm("CloseFrontEnd[]", 0);
        kernelLink.close();
```

Comment: This doesn't help you, but I get this message all the time when I interrupt Mathematica when running from the console. Clicking "yes" seems to work without causing any negative side effects.

Comment: @barrycarter I am worrying about any negative effect when I deploy this application in linux server. Because there's no UI to let me click 'yes'

Comment: I don't have a way to test this, but would `Quiet` suppress the popup?